# Question regarding using function c() in R coding

Tags: r, function, vector

I am studying Data analyitcs, my teacher give a question for class "using one-sigma to find any outlier in vector D". He gave his answere as below but I do not understand why he called Out=c() before using function "for" and called "Out" again in fumction c(Out,o)? Could you help me answer this question? Thank you!

```
D=c(4,6,1,2,8,11)  
xbar=mean(D)  
std=sd(D)  
L=xbar-std  
U=xbar+std
Out=c()
for(j in 1:length(D)){
if(D[j]<L | D[j]>U) {o=D[j]} else{o=NULL}  Out=c(Out,o)}
```

Comment: For help on `c()`, enter `?c` in the console. It says that `c()` is a function to combine values into a vector or list. Typically, there are multiple elements inside the parentheses, like `c(1, 2, 10)`. If they're empty, like here, it's equivalent to writing `Out = NULL`, which means that an object called `Out`  was created, but it's empty. The loop in the last two lines progressively adds additional elements to it, so it grows from having no elements (empty), to one element, to two, to three, etc.

Comment: @JonSpring, please post this as an answer!

Comment: FWIW this code is easy to understand but not a very good model of how to code in R ... `outliers <- D[abs(scale(D))>1]` would solve the same problem ...

Comment: @JonSpring in this case, do we need to name the object matching or not? For example:  ```Out1=c()```    ```Out=c(Out1,o)```

Answer (score 0):

`Out=c()` is your output. It's just an empty dataframe in the beginning.  The `for` loop is iterating `j` in the `length D`. So for each `j` observation, it's performing the conditional statement `if(D[j]<L | D[j]>U) {o=D[j]} else{o=NULL}` and then putting the results in the Output `Out` Hope this helps.

Comment: I can understand this but when we put Out again in the function Out=c(Out,o)???

Answer (score 0):

The need for an object named `Out` to exist before entering a `for`-loop is based on how the `c` and `[<-` functions are designed. They need names to exist in the table of objects that the R interpreter maintains, You used "=" but in that context it is really the `<-` function, the assignment operator, that is being used. The code in the question doesn't appear to use that operator, but it is actually being called when the "=" sign in `Out=c(Out,o)` is used. You cannot assign a value to the `Out` on the LHS of the assignment by appending to it because the `Out` in the RHS  doesn't already a value (not even a value of length-0) within the R data objects list when the`c`-function tries to access its value.

The `<-` operator is really a function disguised as an infix operator. You can demonstrate this with:

```
`<-`(my.out , 4)

> my.out
[1] 4
```

It also has an indexed assignment version `[<-` which requires that the named  object on the LHS exist. This is another source of error for for-loop users. If the named LHS object given to `[<-` doesn't exist at the time the loop is run, then the first time through the loop you will get and error:

```
rm(my.out2)  #make sure it doesn't exist
for (i in 1:10) { my.out2[i] <- 4 }  # LHS doesn't exist, but RHS value exists
#Error: object 'my.out2' not found
```